# Printing the HRESULT symbol in a string (e.g. E_FAIL as a CString)

Tags: c++, winapi

I would like to print the error HRESULT "#define"-symbol in a textbox for instance, but I can't seem to find how to do that. When I search online, all I find is how to get the error description text etc.

This is how I would like to have a part of my textbox output:

```
Error: 0x80040E01 (DB_E_ROWLIMITEXCEEDED)
```

etc for all possible error codes.
The hexadecimal value and error description texts I get successfully by using the _com_error err(hr) method. So that is all fine, but I connect get the messageID (DB_E_ROWLIMITEXCEEDED in this example) printed as a string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: One approach to save you doing this entirely by hand would be to write some code that parses the include files containing the definitions and outputs code that does the conversion.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, it actually crossed my mind...at least I know what is possible and what is not now so I can re-evaluate my alternatives with regard to the "ROI" that I get from it :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [`FACILITY_ITF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679751.aspx) error code. You can tell that from the 4th hex digit being 4. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690088.aspx) says:

> The actual meaning of the error is defined by the interface. That is, two HRESULTs with exactly the same 32-bit value returned from two different interfaces might have different meanings.

Because this error is defined by the interface, and is not system defined, it is the responsibility of the interface to provide any descriptive text for the error. If the interface fails to do so, then you are pretty much stuck. The best you can do I suppose is to recognise the particular interface, and then you provide the missing text.

Comment: Okay, like I suspected...I really thought there would be /some/ other way to print those #Defines. I'm interested in the error codes defined in atldbcli.h in particular. It provides descriptive text, but all I wanted was to have a complementary error id symbol. If I see something like E_LOGIN_FAILED then I don't need the long descriptive text at all times. I hoped to avoid long switch/cases of if/elses. :/

Comment: In the past I used a static map for that.

Comment: I'm just puzzled how this guy seems to have managed to do this, or am I missing something? http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?467205-HRESULT-to-string

@drescherjm Yes, a map would be possible, but I still have to construct it in some un-pretty large code block somewhere?

Comment: Well, that link seems unrelated to this issue. You can readily get hold of the info for system defined error codes. It is interface defined ones that are more thorny.

Comment: @10100111001: `FormatMessage()` retrieves human readible error messages, not error code names. For example, passing an error code of `E_UNEXPECTED` to `FormatMessage()` returns a string of `"Unexpected failure"`. It cannot convert `0x80040E01` to `DB_E_ROWLIMITEXCEEDED`, you have to use your own lookup tables for that kind of conversion.